# how to validate a specific email pattern in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am currently designing a sign up page, in my `model/user.rb` file, how do I specify that only these email addresses ending with `@gmail.com` can be successfully registered?
Thank you

Comment: how about googlemail? or custom domains that use gmail?

Answer (score 1):

I would set up 2 validations:

- the first one validates the email address is valid, using your preferred email regex (I'm providing one for the example, [source](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_format_of)):

  ```
  EMAIL_REGEX = /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
  validates_format_of :email, with: EMAIL_REGEX
  ```
- a second one that validates the email addresses's domain:

  ```
  GMAIL_DOMAINS = %w{gmail.com googlemail.com}

  validates :email_is_gmail

  private
  def email_is_gmail
    GMAIL_DOMAINS.each do |domain|
      return true if email.end_with?('@' + domain)
    end
  end
  ```

Warnings:

- Regarding the first validation, I would advise you to make sure that different parts of your code do not use different regular expressions to validate an email address. For example, if you are using Devise, you should use `Devise.email_regexp` instead of `EMAIL_REGEX`. (Actually, if you use Devise or similar, you shouldn't even have to validate email addresses yourself).

  Using different regular expressions in different parts of your code can lead to creating accounts with an email address that validates in some places, but fails validation in others. This can be irritating for end-users. (For an example, see last paragraph on [sub-addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Sub-addressing) on Wikipedia's page about email address, and imagine a site that sometimes allows the `+`, and sometimes does not.)
- As @YOU mentioned in a comment, filtering by domain name might not exactly be what you want. Many Google accounts do not end in `@gmail.com` (eg. googlemail.com or even any business using [GSuite](https://gsuite.google.com/) with their own domain name). If you want to allow only people owning a Google Account, I would advise you to have a look at [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/) authentication system.
- Some people advocate against validating email addresses with a regular expression: [Stop Validating Email Addresses With Regex](https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)

  > Just send them an email already

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this way.

In your model

```
validates :email, format: { with: /^[a-z0-9](\.?[a-z0-9]){5,}@g(oogle)?mail\.com$/i,
message: "Your message" }
```

Also you can change regex.

Answer (score -1):

Use `include` like:

```
email= "user@gmail.com"

email.include? "@gmail.com" #returns true
```